# Powershell script started failing to add new release variable via the API "Error: An empty body in the POST request is not allowed"

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

```
Powershell script is setting new release variable but it started failing suddenly

$url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/$releaseId?api-version=5.0"

$releaseDefinition = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers @{ "Authorization"="Bearer     $authenticationToken" "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8" }

$newVariable = New-Object PSObject
$newVariable | Add-Member Noteproperty allowOverride $False 
$newVariable | Add-Member Noteproperty isSecret $secretValue
$newVariable | Add-Member Noteproperty value $variableValue

$serializedVariable = $newVariable | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3
$deserializedVariable = $serializedVariable | ConvertFrom-Json
```

** This is problematic line.If i comment out this line then request doesn't fail.When I log the    releaseDefinition.variables and i see new variable is added.**

```
$releaseDefinition.variables | Add-Member -Name $variableName -Value $deserializedVariable -   MemberType NoteProperty -Force

$requestBody = ConvertTo-Json $releaseDefinition -Depth 100

#Error throw here when we add new release variable
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Headers @{ "Authorization"="Bearer     $authenticationToken" "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8" } -Body $requestBody
```

**Error message:
"Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"VS402865: An empty body in the POST request is not allowed.""**

Comment: $requestBody is null so you do not have any body.  So $releaseDefinition is failing or is also null.  So you need $myVariable = $releaseDefinition.variables | Add-Member -Name $variableName -Value $deserializedVariable -   MemberType NoteProperty -Force and then use $myVariable in $serializedVariable = $myVariable | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3

Comment: @nhs, i tried your script and fixed some syntax errors. I used accesstoken as bearer token, and give `project collection build service` account `Edit release pipeline` permission so that the token can add the variable to the release run. Please check the details in the reply below. If you use other bearer token, it's same way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As per the error `VS402865: An empty body in the POST request is not allowed.`, it's recommended to output the `$requestBody` content for a check.

I tried your script and fixed some syntax, it works on my side. I used `system.accesstoken` as the `bearer token` and add powershell task in DevOps release:

1. Enable the option on agent job level:

[image]

2. The PowerShell script:

```
$url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$(orgname)/$(projectname)/_apis/release/releases/$(Release.ReleaseId)?api-version=5.0"


$secretValue = "false"
$override = "false"
$variableValue = "var3value4"
$variableName = "var3"


$releaseDefinition = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers @{"Authorization"="Bearer    $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"; "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8" }

$newVariable = New-Object PSObject
$newVariable | Add-Member Noteproperty allowOverride $override 
$newVariable | Add-Member Noteproperty isSecret $secretValue
$newVariable | Add-Member Noteproperty value $variableValue

$serializedVariable = $newVariable | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3
$deserializedVariable = $serializedVariable | ConvertFrom-Json

$releaseDefinition.variables | Add-Member -Name $variableName -Value $deserializedVariable -MemberType NoteProperty -Force

$requestBody = ConvertTo-Json $releaseDefinition -Depth 100

echo $requestBody

#Error throw here when we add new release variable
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Headers @{"Authorization"="Bearer     $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"; "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8" } -Body $requestBody
```

Release task succeeds:

[image]

Variable added:

[image]